# Summing two equal means with equal standard deviations and calculating the sum's resultant standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

Having looked at the discussions for similar questions I find none quite equate with this apparently simple case I present here.

It has been calculated that the average age between female generations in the past is 23.2 years +/-3 (1 sigma).

So if I go back two generations this will be on average 46.4 years, but what is the standard deviation now? Is it just the sum of the variance (ie the variance of 9 doubled) that results in an SD of 4.2?

If I go back three generations the time difference will be 69.6 years +/-?

Should be very straightforward?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is if you assume that the average ages between generations are independent from one generation to another.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I assume we have to taken this number is based on average genetic mutation rates. But to go back three generations then do we just take the new SD of 4.2 for two generations and the SD of 3 for one generation, so adding the two variances would get 69.9 with a SD of 5.2?